# Convert an array to a list in PureScript

Tags: arrays, list, purescript

**XY problem**

How do I convert an array to a list in PureScript?

```
arrayToList :: forall a. Array a -> List a
arrayToList = ???
```

**Actual problem**

Must I *necessarily* write this function?

Neither `purescript-arrays` nor `purescript-lists` define such a function, which leads me wonder if there is an idiomatic way to deal with arrays in the contexts of functions taking a list.

For example [Matrix.getRow](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-matrices/2.0.0/docs/Matrix#v:getRow) returns an *array* which needs to be transformed into a *list* of [Pux Html elements](http://www.alexmingoia.com/purescript-pux/docs/API/Pux/Html.html) (in the process of rendering the matrix as HTML). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With compiler [version 0.10.2](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/releases/tag/v0.10.2), you can simply write

```
arrayToList :: forall a. Array a -> List a
arrayToList = ?whatGoesHere
```

and the compiler will give you a list of things to fill in, based on the type information. `?whatGoesHere` is called a *typed hole*.

In this case, you probably want `Data.Array.toUnfoldable` or `Data.List.fromFoldable`.

Comment: Just needed a function `Data.List.Lazy.List a -> Data.Array a`, and `toUnfoldable` worked as well.